# DateTime.TryParse returning wrong (IMO) answer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime

I have an old asp classic VB script that was converted to run in VB .NET long ago that is a mess but I can't get approval to rewrite it yet.

In there it had a function that takes a string and attempts to handle it properly based on its content.

It was originally written as:

```
Public Shared Function fx(ByVal _str As String) As String
    If IsDate(_str) Then
        'Dates have to be formated just right for MySQL to accept them
        fx = DatePart("yyyy", _str) & "-" & DatePart("m", _str) & "-" & DatePart("d", _str)
    ElseIf IsNumeric(_str) Then
        'Numbers go in just fine
        fx = _str
    ElseIf Len(_str) > 0 Then
        'If it's not a date and not a number then treat it as a text field and filter it so that MySQL will take it
        _str = Trim(_str) 'First trim off any leading and trailing spaces
        _str = Replace(_str, "\", "\\") 'Change all \ to \\  
        _str = Replace(_str, "'", "''") 'Change all ' to ''         
        fx = _str
    Else
        fx = ""
    End If
End Function
```

My problem comes when I use pass fx the value "11.16" and it says "Oh yes, that's a date - 2015/11/16"

I tried using `success = DateTime.TryParse(_str,tempDate)` but it behaves the same.

What is the best way to do this if _str being passed in can be anything from a blank string to a date to a dollar amount to a street address?  The obvious is to rewrite the calling code but with the legacy code that's not terribly practical.  Any suggestion appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `TryParseExact`?

Comment: I would use `TryParseExact` and supply an array of formats that constitute an acceptable `DateTime`

Comment: You could try testing IsNumeric before IsDate

Comment: The `TryParseExact` with an array of formats will work for me but I need to make some calling code changes I was hoping to avoid but that's the nature of the code I inherited.  Thanks!  

I can't change the order without breaking other things - it's really a mess in there and needs a rewrite, but thanks for the idea.

If you want credit, Andrew, make your comment an answer.  Yours was the most helpful although the others were useful.

Comment: Are you really passing dates to MySql as strings?  Is the column in your database a `DateTime`?  It seems to me that using a parameterized query with a proper `DateTime` variable would eliminate the need to do these string gymnastics.

Comment: Great point Chris.  We are working with other systems that don't allow this, unfortunately.  I can't adjust the db and it's a varchar there.  It's one of those "The whole system needs reworking but who has the resources?" situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew Whitaker's answer of `TryParseExact` and an array of date formats is the best answer to my particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Shared Function fx(ByVal _str As String) As String
    If IsDate(_str) Then
        'Dates have to be formated just right for MySQL to accept them
        fx = DatePart("yyyy", _str) & "-" & DatePart("m", _str) & "-" & DatePart("d", _str)
    ElseIf IsNumeric(_str) Then
        'Numbers go in just fine
        fx = _str
    ElseIf Len(_str) > 0 Then
        'If it's not a date and not a number then treat it as a text field and filter it so that MySQL will take it
        _str = Trim(_str) 'First trim off any leading and trailing spaces
        _str = Replace(_str, "\", "\\") 'Change all \ to \\  
        _str = Replace(_str, "'", "''") 'Change all ' to ''         
        fx = _str
    Else
        fx = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: If you're answering a 6 year old question with an accepted answer, it would be much better to explain the benefits of your answer so that people don't have to guess, or work it out for themselves.